# Sidr pre-load bug

Tags: jquery, html, sidr

I am using Sidr sidebar for my filter search on my site. The site is almost done however there is one problem. The content of the sidebar appears (without its css style for about a second) first on load before the whole site loads fully. It appears something like this:
http://bit.ly/1sz3W6N

It's a screenshot by my client. I think it only appears when the load is slow because from my side everything seems to work smoothly.

I am clueless on how I can solve this. Help?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Putting an inline display none on the sidr main container worked for me.

```
<div id="sidr" style="display:none">
```